# Accelerate css's skew() by mousewheel in a js animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

Yesterday I was browsing the internet and found this great website: https://durimel.io/nel.
Just look at how his works are listed… an infinite list with the works even skewing on mouse scroll.

I love that thing! So, I started to think about how it could have been done and started to experiment a bit on my own. I want to make clear, that my purpose is not to copying Lionel’s work… I just want to learn and understand how to build such a fantastic animation! (And perhaps use some similar concepts in the future )

Now to my question:
If you look at my code, I think that my list is (more or less) moving right. It is infinite, it scrolls faster or slower depending on the times the mouse wheel is used. As for that it should be ok

But the skew() function does not behave correctly. What am I missing here?
It does not have a real/good acceleration, as it does not skew less on a single scroll or more on longer scrolls. In addition, if you try to scroll up and down consecutively it lags and judders.
How can I resolve that problem?

Here is my code so far. And please don’t ask my why I used such strange numbers or calculations… I don’t know, I was just playing around with them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            display: inline;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 90pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: solid 1px red;

            position: absolute;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transform-origin: 50% 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>bla bla</li>
    <li>adsf</li>
    <li>234 777</li>
    <li>jhgj</li>
    <li>shsh hshs</li>
    <li>looool</li>
    <li>gaga</li>
</ul>

<script>
    let a = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    let ticking = false;
    let trans3d = 0;
    let listEnd = 0;
    let listStart = 0;

    window.onload = function () {
        let pos = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            let prev = (i > 0) ? a[i - 1].offsetWidth + 20 : 0;
            pos += prev;
            a[i].style.left = pos + "px";

            if (pos >= listEnd) {
                listEnd = pos + a[i].offsetWidth + 20;
            }
            if (pos <= listStart) {
                listStart = pos;
            }
        }
    }

    function changeListPos(item, moveToEnd) {
        if (moveToEnd) {
            item.style.left = listEnd + "px";
            listEnd += item.offsetWidth + 20;
            listStart += item.offsetWidth + 20;
        } else {
            listStart -= item.offsetWidth + 20;
            listEnd -= item.offsetWidth + 20;
            item.style.left = listStart + "px";
        }
    }

    function scrollContent(scroll_pos) {
        let qtyScroll = 40;
        let easeOutSine = function (t, b, c, d) {
            return c * Math.sin(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + b;
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < qtyScroll; i++) {
            (function (x) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    trans3d += easeOutSine(x, ((qtyScroll - x)) / 14, 0.05, qtyScroll) * (scroll_pos / Math.abs(scroll_pos));
                    let skew = easeOutSine(x, ((qtyScroll - x)) / 6, 0.05, qtyScroll) * (scroll_pos / Math.abs(scroll_pos));
                    console.log(skew);

                    for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                        let prev = (j == 0) ? a[a.length - 1] : a[j - 1]
                        let curr = a[j];

                        if (scroll_pos < 0 && curr.getBoundingClientRect().x < -(prev.getBoundingClientRect().width / 4) && parseInt(prev.style.left) < parseInt(curr.style.left)) {
                            changeListPos(prev, true);
                        } else if (scroll_pos > 0 && curr.getBoundingClientRect().x >= -(prev.getBoundingClientRect().width / 4) && parseInt(prev.style.left) > parseInt(curr.style.left)) {
                            changeListPos(prev, false);
                        }

                        curr.style.transform = "skew(" + skew + "deg) translate3d(" + trans3d + "px, 0px, 0px)";
                    }
                }, 55 * (x / 3));
            })(i);
        }
    }

    (function (window, document) {

        let prefix = "", _addEventListener, support;

        // detect event model
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            _addEventListener = "addEventListener";
        } else {
            _addEventListener = "attachEvent";
            prefix = "on";
        }

        // detect available wheel event
        support = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : // Modern browsers support "wheel"
            document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : // Webkit and IE support at least "mousewheel"
                "DOMMouseScroll"; // let's assume that remaining browsers are older Firefox

        window.addWheelListener = function (elem, callback, useCapture) {
            _addWheelListener(elem, support, callback, useCapture);

            // handle MozMousePixelScroll in older Firefox
            if (support == "DOMMouseScroll") {
                _addWheelListener(elem, "MozMousePixelScroll", callback, useCapture);
            }
        };

        function _addWheelListener(elem, eventName, callback, useCapture) {
            elem[_addEventListener](prefix + eventName, support == "wheel" ? callback : function (originalEvent) {
                !originalEvent && (originalEvent = window.event);

                // create a normalized event object
                var event = {
                    // keep a ref to the original event object
                    originalEvent: originalEvent,
                    target: originalEvent.target || originalEvent.srcElement,
                    type: "wheel",
                    deltaMode: originalEvent.type == "MozMousePixelScroll" ? 0 : 1,
                    deltaX: 0,
                    deltaY: 0,
                    deltaZ: 0,
                    preventDefault: function () {
                        originalEvent.preventDefault ?
                            originalEvent.preventDefault() :
                            originalEvent.returnValue = false;
                    }
                };

                // calculate deltaY (and deltaX) according to the event
                if (support == "mousewheel") {
                    event.deltaY = -1 / 40 * originalEvent.wheelDelta;
                    // Webkit also support wheelDeltaX
                    originalEvent.wheelDeltaX && (event.deltaX = -1 / 40 * originalEvent.wheelDeltaX);
                } else {
                    event.deltaY = originalEvent.deltaY || originalEvent.detail;
                }

                // it's time to fire the callback
                return callback(event);

            }, useCapture || false);
        }

    })(window, document);

    addWheelListener(window, function (e) {
        if (!ticking) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                scrollContent(e.deltaY);
                ticking = false;
            });

            ticking = true;
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a transition delay on `skew` for the `li` elements, the skew wil feel sligthly more "realistic"

`transition: skew 1.5s;`

In your style block:

```
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            display: inline;
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 90pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: solid 1px red;

            position: absolute;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transform-origin: 50% 100%;
            transition: skew 1.5s;
        }
    </style>
```

If you want to change the angle of the skew, just alter the code where the `skew` variable is initiated inside the `scrollContent()` function:

```
let skew = easeOutSine(x, ((qtyScroll - x)) / 6, 0.1, qtyScroll) * (scroll_pos / Math.abs(scroll_pos));
```

You can for example change the `/ 6` to `/ 3` to get a bigger `skew`. If you do so, you might want to increase the `transition: skew` to 2 or 3s instead.